# R multinomial logistic regresion, Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a csv file on which I want to fit a multinomial regression model. My dependent variable is 'topic' (the first column in the csv) and I have 200 factors (named X0 ... X199).
I tried:

```
require(nnet)

mydata <- read.csv('data/data.csv')
mydata$topic <- factor(mydata$topic)
colnames(mydata)
```

Which results in

```
[1] "topic" "X0"    "X1"    "X2"    "X3"    "X4"    "X5" ....
```

Now I want a multinomial logistic regression model:

```
x = paste('X0', paste('+',paste('X', 1:199, sep=''), sep='', collapse=" "))
vars = paste('topic ~ ', x ,sep='', collapse=" ")
print(vars)
```

output:

```
topic ~ X0 +X1 +X2 +X3 +X4 +X5 +X6 +X7 +X8 +X9 +....
```

Fitting the multinomial model:

```
test <- multinom(vars, data=mydata, MaxNWts=2000)
```

output:

```
....
iter  80 value 23059.928035
iter  90 value 23055.453099
iter 100 value 23051.468665
final  value 23051.468665 
stopped after 100 iterations
```

Now when I ask for the summary of the model:

```
summary(test)
```

I get this error:

> `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'topic' not found`

However when I type in the exact variables instead of passing them as an string (the variable `vars` above), it works. i.e.

```
test <- multinom('topic ~ X0 + X1 + X2', data=mydata, MaxNWts=2000)
```

what is wrong with my `vars` which contains all the factors and the topic?

Comment: from `nnet` package @user20650

Comment: @user20650 Interesting! I was following this tutorial:
http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

Comment: user; yup that does seem to work..hmm

Comment: wrap it in `formula`. As n `test <- multinom(formula(vars), data=mydata, MaxNWts=2000)`, then `summary` seems to work

Comment: @user20650 
That was it 
`formula(vars)` worked. Thanks!

Comment: user292139; good stuff, please feel free to write it as an answer. Wrapping it in `formula` seems to do something to the structure of the returned object... hmmm